# How do I create a ssh key on a azure virtual machine using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I Want to create a new ssh key on an azure virtual machine using terraform?

I tried this but didn't work.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "cat /dev/zero | ssh-keygen -q -N ''"
  ]
}
}
```

It gives this error.

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [5m30s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   Host:
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   User: root
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   Password: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   Private key: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [5m40s elapsed]


Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (root@:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add a connection in the provisioner "remote-exec".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension"`. It does not need SSH key. Like so:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "<some_name>"
  location             = "<resource_group_location>"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.<resource_group>.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.<vm>.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "<your_command>"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Note, this is just single command execution. If you want multiple commands to be executed you can create a shell script, upload it (so it is publicly accessible) and do:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "<some_name>"
  location             = "<resource_group_location>"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.<resource_group>.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.<vm>.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
    "fileUris": ["https://url/to/file/<file>.sh"],
    "commandToExecute": "sh <file>.sh"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```